# Both side voice call recording is not working on some Xiaomi and samsung devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-ndk, call-recording

I have developed a call recording app, it's working fine on pure android devices, however its not recording other person's voice in Xiaomi and samsung devices but it is recording mine perfectly,

Here is my code

```
mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
    mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
    mediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
    val recordingFileName: String = getRandomRecordFileName(callType)
    recordingFileNameForNotification = recordingFileName
    mediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(recordingFileName)
    try {
        mediaRecorder!!.prepare()
        Log.i("CAL", "media prepared")
        Log.i("CAL", "media record")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("CALL", "could'nt prepare")
        //e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        mediaRecorder!!.start()
        Log.i("CALL", "Recording Started")
        isRecording = true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("CALL", "couldn't start recording")
    }
```

I have heard that i need to use ndk,but don't know how to d that
can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Using the NDK would not make a difference. Either the platform implements voice call recording or it doesn't; there's nothing you can do about it at the application layer. However, the appropriate audio source to use is `VOICE_CALL`, not `VOICE_COMMUNICATION`.

Comment: I have seen call recording apps in play store recording without any issue on certain devices which i mentioned above ,By the way i tried, the app did't record the conversation an empty recording file was created, with VOICE_COMMUNICATION the recording is working on pure android 8.1

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out which `AudioSource` they are using. Just run `adb shell dumpsys media.audio_flinger` while one of those apps are recording, and then find the `Audio source:` line for the input thread.

Comment: Thanks once again @Michael, I'll try.

Comment: I ran that command while the other app was recording, here is the excerpt from the output  : `(AUDIO_DEVICE_IN_TELEPHONY_RX|AUDIO_DEVICE_IN_VOICE_CALL)
  Audio source: 4 (voice call)
  AudioStreamIn: 0xeddd06e0 flags 0 (AUDIO_INPUT_FLAG_NONE)`

Comment: So can you please tell, what can i do next with my above code with the above `adb` command output ?

Comment: They're using the `VOICE_CALL` audio source, as I suggested in one of my previous comments. Have you made sure to obtain the `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission that the documentation states that you need?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, yes i research about it, but i heard that `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` is a special permission, so I'm afraid to use it because google may remove or suspend my app from play store for asking this special permission, what do you think ?, can i use this above mentioned permission without any tension ?

Comment: Ah, right, it's a system permission. It doesn't seem like Google wants 3rd party apps to be able to record voice calls anymore. Perhaps it'll work if you lower your targetSdkVersion to something really old (like 18). I don't know. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: Oh yeah, the other app which i was talking about targets API level 21. Thank you so much for clarifying my doubts :)

Comment: Even with `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` it isn't working and I explored their `AndroidManifest.xml` for requested permissions, i didn't find a line asking for this capture_audio_output permission.

Comment: Michael if you are here, I think probably they were routing incoming audio from somewhere to their destination (I don't know technically how it works) here is the output of the `adb shell shell dumpsys media.audio_flinger `
`Channel mask: 0x00000010 (front)
  Processing format: 0x1 (AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_16_BIT)
  Processing frame size: 2 bytes
  Pending config events:
    KeyValue: input_source=4;routing=-2147483584;format=1
Local log:
   07-23 03:03:28.896 CFG_EVENT_SET_PARAMETER: (input_source=4;routing=-2147483584;format=1) configuration changed`

Comment: @kenchl Any update? Were are able to achive recording calls (both side)?